# How to set nginx ingress rate limit per day?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am using aws eks. I need additional local rate limit per day condition. Is there any way to do?


I know about

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rpm 
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps
```

This is the code.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: "5"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rpm: "10"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx 
  rules:
  - host: "*"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: suffix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port: 
              number: 5000
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the global-rate-limit with `global-rate-limit-window: 24h`.
See https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#global-rate-limiting.

For instance, a configuration for allowing 1000 requests in a 24h time frame:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/global-rate-limit: "1000"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/global-rate-limit-key: global
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/global-rate-limit-window: 24h
```

The downside is that using the global rate limiting feature requires a memcache instance to be deployed and running in your cluster.